# How to use RTK query result with localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I created an api endpoint with createApi Fn. I need to store response data in localStorage for some time and get it from LS instead of making requests. And when timer is over update data with useQuery.

```
export const geoApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'geoApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: GEO_URL }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getData: builder.query<any, void>({
            query: () => 'geo-data',
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useGetDataQuery } = geoApi;
```

I can make it **inside component** logic (pseudo code):

```
let geoData = null;
const cachedData = ls.get('GEO_DATA');

if (cachedData && dataIsUpToDate()) {
  geoData = cachedData;
} else {
  const res = useGetDataQuery();

  geoData = res.data;
  updateCachedData(geoData);
}
```

But I would like to do it within redux store logic.

Comment: hello did you found out solution. help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I suggest to use the hook (modify it for your case):

```
function useCachedData(key, ttl = Infinity, query) {
    const [trigger] = query();
    const [data, updateData] = useState();

    const refreshCache = async () => {
        const fetched = await trigger();

        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({ at: Date.now(), data: fetched.data });

        updateData(fetched.data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const cached = localStorage.getItem(key);
        let isValid = false;
        if (cached) {
            const { at, data } = JSON.parse(cached);

            if (at + ttl > Date.now()) {
                isValid = true;
                updateData(data);
            }
        }

        if (!isCached) {
            refreshCache();
        }
    }, []);

    return data;
}
```

And usage with [lazy query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery):

```
// ...component logic
const geoData = useCachedData('GEO_DATA', 60 * 1000, () => useLazyQuery());
```